# .htaccess Разрешить доступ к папке

Tags: .htaccess

В DLE, в папке /engine/modules есть файл .htaccess  с таким содержанием

```
Order Deny,
Allow Deny from all
```

Насколько я понял, эти команды запрещяют отображение всех файлов и папок, мне нужно дать доступ на отображение файлов из папки /engine/modules/tv/img_logo

Пробовал так

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
<Files "tv/img_logo">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

но ничего не помогает, как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так правильней

```
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: мне нужно было тоьлко для одной папки доступ дать

решил так
<Files "tv/img_logo">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

Answer (score 1):

Или

```
##
## White listed folders
##
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/имя папки/.*
```